# Port UNIX sockets to windows without winsock. Really?

Tags: windows, sockets, unix, winsock, mingw32

I have some code that using UNIX sockets. But I need to compile it for winodws(using mingw32 on mac os x) but I don't want to use winsock because I'm worried about compatibility! Is there is a way to use UNIX sockets on windows?

Comment: This seems to have (somewhat) been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937914/bsd-socket-compatible-wrapper-around-winsock

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to the BSD API that Winsock provides then you wont have that many problems. A small amount of start up and shutdown code will be Windows specific but most of the socket code will be cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/), they make every effort to be compatible.  However, I have no idea how you would cross-compile for that environment on Mac OSX.

Comment: I don't want to use cygwin because my program will need cygin.dll. I need only one exe that can be launched on any win system.