# Linux and Windows socket APIs

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, winsock

I want to port some Linux-specific code to Windows which contains socket operations. Is there any third party library available for Linux/BSD sockets to Winsock mapping like the pthread-w32 library, which is used for the threading operation? Also, I can't use the Cygwin tool chain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BSD socket compatible wrapper around winsock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937914/bsd-socket-compatible-wrapper-around-winsock)

Comment: I dont get your problem, isn't WSAPI exactly that what your asking for? its almost the same as the BSDsockets, only the wrapper and 1 or two typedeffs are different, arent they?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still working on this, but it's a start for new programs: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libxc/